# Selenium Web Driver firefox not responding

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using simple selenium example using Web driver classes, but the IE web driver class working fine, but the Firefox is not responding not opening browser and not throwing any error in console.

code is here

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

    public class GoogleSearchFF {  
        public static void main(String args[]){  
            WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();  
            System.out.println("Loading Google search page");  
            driver.get("http://www.google.com");
            System.out.println("Google search page loaded fine");   
        }  
    }
```

selenium jar files added to classpath..

> \selenium-java-2.13.0\selenium-2.13.0\selenium-java-2.13.0.jar
>
> \selenium-java-client-driver-1.0.1\selenium-java-client-driver.jar
>
> \Selenium Latest\selenium-server-standalone-2.13.0.jar

any jar is missing?
The code works for IE by setting proeprty INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS = true

Comment: Which version of firefox are you using?

Comment: Mozilla Firefox 16.0.2

Comment: One possible workaround is updating the selenium jar files with latest files. you can download them from [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).

Comment: Have you know what is compatible FF version for this selenium jars?

Comment: As per [this](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/java/CHANGELOG) link, the supported firefox version for selenium 2.13.0 would be Firefox 8. Not more than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrade the Firefox version to 8 as Selenium 2.13.0 supports Firefox versions upto 8 only.

For reference check [this](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/java/CHANGELOG) log.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of downgrading Firefox to 8, 
You need to download the geckodriver.exe and set the System.property() by

System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "pathTogeckodriver");

before calling WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();